# How to declare global variable that is visible to imported module functions

Tags: python

Any `global` variable declared inside of imported .py module remains to be global "within" its own module and it is global "within" a script or a program to where this module was imported (using Python `import` command).
Now what if after importing a module `X` I declare a global variable `Y`. And I want to make a variable Y "visible" or `global` to functions defined in the imported module `X` (so I don't have to pass `Y` to the imported module functions as the argument)?

#### to be imported "myModule.py"  :

```
def printX():
    print variableX

def printY():
    global variableY
    variableY='y'
    print variableY
```

#### Main Programm

```
import myModule as myModule
myModule.printY()
print myModule.variableY

global variableX
variableX='X'
print variableX

myModule.printX() # this will result to NameError
```

---

`myModule.printX()` results to:

```
NameError: global name 'variableX' is not defined
```

Comment: You can't.  If one module needs something from another module, it needs to import that module (or you need to pass it in, e.g., as a parameter to functions you call in the module).

Comment: `"You can't"` is pretty rare response on stackoverflow....

Comment: If `from myModule import printX` doesn't do it, then I don't think anything will.

Comment: You could do `myModule.variableX = 'X'` to define a variable in the other module, but you'd still have to define it "manually" in the "main program", and the two variables wouldn't be linked.  There's no way to make a variable in one module that is automatically "synced" to variables in other modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the function `printX` looks for global `variableX` within `myModule`. That is where you should declare your variable:

```
import myModule as myModule
myModule.printY()
print myModule.variableY

myModule.variableX = 10
print myModule.variableX

myModule.printX()
```

Comment: Note, though, that doing this does *not* make a variable in this module (that is, the module containing this code).  It makes it *only* in the other module.  That may be okay with the OP because it's not clear what he's trying to do, but it's not really what the question asked for.

Comment: Also and FWIW it's a very very poor practice.